# Using images in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

So far I have the following code to animate an image shaking:

```
-(void)shakeView {

    CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [shake setDuration:0.1];
    [shake setRepeatCount:2];
    [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
    [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                         CGPointMake(image.jpg.center.x - 5,image.center.y)]];
    [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                       CGPointMake(image.jpg.center.x + 5, image.jpg.center.y)]];
    [image.jpg.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
}
```

However I get the following error: Use of undeclared identifier "image.jpg".
What do I need to do to fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess image is UIImageView. so, just remove .jpg and use it like `[image.layer addAnimation:....`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have an UIImageView defined as this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
```

Then you are able to shake the view with the following code.

```
CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
[shake setDuration:0.1];
[shake setRepeatCount:2];
[shake setAutoreverses:YES];
[shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                     CGPointMake(_imageView.center.x - 5,_imageView.center.y)]];
[shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                   CGPointMake(_imageView.center.x + 5, _imageView.center.y)]];
[_imageView.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
```

Just replace image.jpg with _imageView.